# (How) can I use an action list with a radio group?

Tags: delphi

For some reason, I never used action lists before. Now that I look at them they seem like A good thing.

However, I am not sure if I can use them with a `TRadioGroup`.

If I have a radio group with two options, (how) can I assign one `TAction` to each?

Comment: IIRC a radio group doesn't provide all that much "access" to its radio buttons. If you want separate actions for each radio button, you might have to use a group box with separate individual radio buttons.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Well, you still can reach them enumerating through RadioGroup.Components - but that was hardly expected use of RG :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usefulness of this answer depends heavily on what kind of action, if any, must be done when you choose such radio button. An action normally allows an application to centralize the response to user commands, not to user preferences or user choices.

But for argument's sake, I imagine a two-way layout of a form, which is controlled by either two menu items, two buttons, or in your case, two radio buttons.

The short answer is: a RadioGroup has no `Action` property and no action can be assigned.

A workaround can be made by the use of a common `GroupBox`, filled with two separate RadioButtons, because a common `RadioButton` dóes have an `Action` property. To get actions behave like radio items, set the `GroupIndex` property of them to the same value.

Example DFM:

```
  object GroupBoxLayout: TGroupBox
    Left = 7
    Top = 7
    Width = 99
    Height = 71
    Caption = 'Form Layout'
    TabOrder = 0
    object RadioButton1: TRadioButton
      Left = 14
      Top = 21
      Width = 113
      Height = 17
      Action = ActionLayoutHorz
      TabOrder = 0
      TabStop = True
    end
    object RadioButton2: TRadioButton
      Left = 14
      Top = 42
      Width = 113
      Height = 17
      Action = ActionLayoutVert
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
  object Actions: TActionList
    Left = 119
    Top = 7
    object ActionLayoutHorz: TAction
      Category = 'Layout'
      Caption = 'Horizontal'
      Checked = True
      GroupIndex = 1
      OnExecute = ActionLayoutHorzExecute
    end
    object ActionLayoutVert: TAction
      Category = 'Layout'
      Caption = 'Vertical'
      GroupIndex = 1
      OnExecute = ActionLayoutVertExecute
    end
  end
```

Example code:

```
procedure TForm1.ActionLayoutHorzExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormLayout := flHorizontal;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActionLayoutVertExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormLayout := flVertical;
end;
```

Note that such `OnExecute` event handler is immediately invoked when you click the corresponding radio button. (This in contrast to a more default-like implementation wherein the choice is taken in effect after the click on a separate OK button.) If that is what you want; go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Actions represent, well, actions. They are associated with UI elements that result in actions: buttons and menu items.

On the other hand a radio group is not used to invoke an action. A radio group is used to make a selection from a mutually exclusive set of options. The individual items in a radio group cannot be assigned an action.

Radio groups do often interact with actions however. But they do so through the OnUpdate handlers of actions that are associated with other UI elements.

For example, consider a form with a button and menu item that are only visible when the radio group has ItemIndex equal to 0. This would be coded with an OnUpdate handler for the action that looked like this:

```
Action.Visible := RadioGroup.ItemIndex=0;
```

And the action itself is associated with the button and the menu item, but not the radio group. It's just that the action's events refer to the radio group's state.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer: Selections from a mutually exclusive set of options often imply actions - particularly changes in state. There is an 'onClick' event handler in TRadioGroup for that.

But TRadioGroup cannot be bound to an action because it is a composite component that could control various actions. Since TRadioGroup does not publish event handlers for each radio button, but relies on the onClick event, Actions become pointless because the action.OnExecute will be bound to the radio group, being obliged to examine the itemIndex property to know which action to perform.

Comment: @Mikey Radio groups are typically used to allow user to specify choices. But you don't expect something to happen when you change the selected item. It's only when you click another button, or somehow invoke an action, that the choice you made is used.

Comment: Understood. Still, there is an OnClick event published for TRadioGroup, implying that sometimes an action might be invoked when changing the selection: If radioButton selections end up driving a particular action,  certainly a good design would use a state variable set by the TRadioGroup.onClick event and not check the itemindex property of a radiogroup - so as a rule, SOMETHING happens when you click the button: a state change of some sort at the least. But I don't disagree with on your basic premise that actions aren't really designed to be bound with radioButtons.

Comment: @Mikey The `OnClick` allows you to respond to changes of the radio group's selected item. Typically this means modifying the data that backs the GUI, and updating the GUI to reflect the new state. That GUI update will often be done by `OnUpdate` handlers, but for actions attached to other widgets.

Comment: Still: 'Action.Visible := RadioGroup.ItemIndex=0;' is IMO not good design - tight coupling: you've bound your action OnUpdate hander to the radioGroup component. Should be done with a state variable set through the radio button.onclick event - indirection. That's why there is a RadioGroup.onClick event: so you can change your state based on the button choice.

Comment: @mikey yes that's right. That's how I do it. But there wasn't space in the answer to build a data binding framework.

Comment: OK understood: that was my only point: RadioButton selections do invoke an action: change of state - that is also an action. You capture that in the OnClick event. But agreed, TAction and TActionList don't really work well here.

Answer (score 1):

Actions are normally associated with "clickable" controls, like buttons and menu's. In that case there is a single input and a single (re)action.

With a listbox there can be several options. And I assume you want an action for each separate option when clicked. If that is the case, you have to do it yourself by using the OnClick event.

```
procedure TForm3.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
    0 : Action1.Execute;
    1 : Action2.Execute;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: which basically defeats the idea of actions ;) Oh, and you did not change radiobuttons captions, hints and perhaps pictures to the ones of ActionX :-) Nnaaah! RadioGroup is one control and can be bound with one Action to work properly, "as designed". Or one better use separate RadioButtons instead. OTOH that m,akes me wonder if there is RadioGroup that bnds with TActionCategory instead...

Comment: The best way is to use another control, or make one yourself.

Comment: @Arioch'The, at least in XE3 a RadioGroup doesn't even have an Action property to bound it to an Action.

Comment: @Uwe that why i asked about existence - i meant 3rd-party one :-)

Comment: @Arioch 'The - How does Toon's approach defeat the idea of actions? Those action.OnExecute events are available to all the components of on the form - they don't only have to be called through the RadioGroup.OnClick event.

Comment: @Mikey Because one of the main points of actions is to avoid handling OnClick events.

Comment: @Mikey Action is not replacement to pointer variable. Action is a method of centralized and automatic assigning to bunch of components the same values for OnClick AND Caption/Title AND Icon/Glyph/Image AND Help-related settings AND Hint-related settings AND state (Visible, Enabled, Checked)... and keyboard also. If you only need procedure pointer - then just declare it. Using TAction to pass one single pointer is the same as using Excel to only calculate 2+2. You can do it, surely so. But it kills the original much complex and smart purpose.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -As I said, those action.OnExecute events are available to all the components of on the form without using the on click event. They are actions, not just handlers for that particular onClick event.

Comment: @Arioch 'The - As I said, those action.OnExecute events are available to all the event handlers on the form that can be bound to an action. The Action.onExecute event does not only service the onclick event - it is bound to an action. The OP wanted to bind to radio buttons but probably has other things to do with the action as well, otherwise certainly this is an exercise in futility. e I understood your intent in your question: you don't use actions just create methods to handle onClick events - I just pointed out that it's not necessarily just that, for my reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your design, but I would not use separate actions in this case, but go this route:

Create an TAction.OnExecute Event such as this:

```
  procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
  begin
      showmessage(   inttostr( (Sender as TRadioGroup).ItemIndex )   );
  end;
```

**In the OnClick event of the radioGroup the drop-down list will show that method: 'Action1Execute'.** Bind it to the RadioGroup.OnClick event - the radioGroup will be passed as 'Sender' into the 'Action1Execute'. By checking the itemindex property:

```
(Sender as TRadioGroup).ItemIndex
```

You can perform whatever operations you like based on the itemIndex, which will tell you which radio button has been clicked. (itemIndex is 0 based).

Generally, cleanest way is as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var index:integer;
begin
  index:=(Sender as TRadioGroup).ItemIndex;
  case index of:
     0: MyFunction1;
     1: MyFunction2;
     2: MyFunction3;
  end;
end;
```

Better not to bind your program logic to event handlers - use indirection by calling other functions.

**If you really need separate actions, create each one with its onExecute event handler and then call them as follows:**

```
 procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var index:integer;
begin
  index:=(Sender as TRadioGroup).ItemIndex;
  case index of:
     0: Action2Execute(sender);
     1: Action3Execute(sender);
     2: Action4Execute(sender);
  end;
end;
```

The drawback to both of these approaches it that your Action1.OnExecute event handler is bound to the radio group. You can negotiate around this:

```
if sender is TRadioGroup then
.....
else
....
```

but this is not clean.

The best solution IMO is Toon Krijthe's

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
    0 : Action1.Execute(sender);
    1 : Action2.Execute(sender);
  end;
end;
```

Even though in the OnClick event of the radioGroup the action.OnExecute is no better than any other function call in that event handler, **in all cases the action items would be available for binding to other components as well - so you can leverage the power of actions in other components on your form that that can be bound to actions.**

As others have stated, perhaps using action items the way you described here is not really appropriate.  I am simply explaining to you that the action.OnExecute event handler can be assigned to the radioGroup onClick event.

Having said that, I would encourage to work more with Actions and ActionLists and use them to handle all of your event management on a form. They help greatly for writing concise, well structured code.

Comment: It pointless to create an action so that you can add an `OnExecute` event, and then assign that event handler to the `OnClick` of the radio group. Delete the action. Create and event handler. Assign that handler to the radio group's `OnClick` event.

Comment: The OP asked how to use actions, with radiobuttons and that's what I explained. I was not concerned with the 'point' of the design. Again - the action are not only avaiable through the onclick event - they are availabe to any event that takes can be assigned to an action, so the concept of actions is not subverted.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your action to the invisible button...
 then use:
`TAction.ExecuteTarget(InvisibleButton);` 
in any place of the application.